# how to apply css for html to pdf convert process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I used iTextSharp to convert pdf from HTML with inline Css, but the css is not applying.

```
                    divPDF.InnerHtml = "<ul style="float:none;width:100%;display:block;list-style:none;margin:0 0 20px 0;padding:0;clear:both"><li style="text-indent:0;"><label style="float:left;width:50%;">Additional Medicare tax (1.45%  + .9%)</label>P1_F1</li><li style="text-indent:0;"><label style="float:left;width:50%;">Additional Obamacare Medicare tax (3.8%)</label>P1_F2</li></ul>";

                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");

                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    divPDF.RenderControl(hw);
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

                    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);


                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                    Response.End();
```

Comment: See this 

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=56

Comment: You're using HTMLWorker. This class has been deprecated in favor of XML Worker: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/